# Nested multi column navigation

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to get started with ember.js and have gone through the 'todo' tutorial as well as read most of the guide. However, I can't get this multi column navigation right and unfortunately haven't been able to find a similar example.

So, I am having multiple columns, let's call the first one a list of gallerys.
When the user selects the gallery, I would like to display all the images in the column next to the list of galleries. In the end I will be having more than two levels, but two should do for now. I have managed to display the list of galleries, but as soon as I select one, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? I am also not quite sure how the best way to map the routes would be.

Here is the link to my code: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gesereyu/1/edit

This is my router config:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('gallerys', { path: '/' }, function() {
    this.resource('gallery', { path: '/:gallery_id'});
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you watch this video? It shows a similar example with blog title and blog description loaded side by side. http://emberjs.com/guides/

Comment: Yes, I did. My main issue with that is that in the video it returns a concrete blog post for a selection, whereas I need to return a list of the following entity. I haven't been able to figure out how I should map that correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your bin a bit. [Here is the working demo.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gesereyu/5/edit) Here are the changes I made.

1. In the link-to helper specify the route in quotes and all the model data that is to be the dynamic segment.

   ```
   {{#link-to "gallery" this.id}}{{name}}{{/link-to}}
   ```
2. Instead of rendering the gallerys directly into the 'gallerys' route, render them into the gallerys/index route. This way you will not need to use the renderTemplate.

   ```
   App.GallerysIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
     model: function () {
       return this.store.find('gallery');
     }
   });
   ```